# Could not read from file C:\Users\Username\React\Final Year Project\client\stream-browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, import

[image]
Getting this error in my VsCode after changing an import line in a js file. I changed it from `const ethSigUtil = require('eth-sig-util)` to 'import 'eth-sig-util' as it was giving me an error previously saying `require is not defined`.

I'm running vite and I'm importing this file in my client side in createNode.js while the file signer.js is in my backend. They're both running tsconfig but these two files are both js files as I couldn't work out the types.

root/client/src/eth/createNode.js
`import { signMetaTransactionRequest } from '../../../backend/src/signer.js';`

root/backend/src/signer.js
`import * as ethSigUtil from 'eth-sig-util';`

The function I'm exporting from signer.js is

```
export async function signMetaTransactionRequest(signer, forwarder, input) {
  const request = await buildRequest(forwarder, input);
  const toSign = await buildTypedData(forwarder, request);
  const signature = await signTypedData(signer, input.from, toSign);
  return { signature, request };
};
```

I've tried changing it to the line above but still the same error. On my actual localhost, the console is giving me this error with the get request being a 504. I've reinstalled node modules and everything but I don't understand this error.
[image]

My package.json in client side has references to them

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.4.2",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.3.2",
    "@react-oauth/google": "^0.12.1",
    "@supabase/auth-ui-react": "^0.4.6",
    "@supabase/auth-ui-shared": "^0.1.8",
    "@supabase/supabase-js": "^2.38.5",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "browserify-zlib": "^0.2.0",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "ethers": "^6.11.1",
    "events": "^3.3.0",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-datepicker": "^4.23.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.48.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.11.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.18.0",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "supabase": "^1.113.3",
    "util": "^0.12.5",
    "zod": "^3.22.4"
  },
```

My package.json in backend

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@chainlink/contracts": "^0.8.0",
    "@metamask/eth-sig-util": "^7.0.1",
    "@openzeppelin/contracts": "^5.0.1",
    "@openzeppelin/defender-relay-client": "^1.54.1",
    "@openzeppelin/defender-sdk": "^1.10.0",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "eth-sig-util": "^3.0.1",
    "ethers": "^6.11.1"
  }
```

I realise that eth-sig-util is deprecated but I still need it. I don't quite understand why the first error image shows that it cant read from client/stream-browserify so maybe its a path issue.

If anyone can help, I would appreciate it. I've been stuck on this for an entire day.